# Security: FTP transfer on a public network

Tags: security, ftp

I have heard of security issues with the way FTP username and password is sent to the server for authentication. Is it safe to use FTP on a public network?

In particular I use Notepad++ with ftp plugin that synch the file with the server on save (via ftp).

Is it unsafe to be on a public network (say a university campus) and use FTP to connect to your server?

Comment: With ftp, your password is sent in the clear (not encrypted), and your connection is susceptible to MITM (man in the middle) attacks. For something more secure, try SFTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of FTP clients have a option to add a security layer. Check this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_client_software) link a comparison of some FTP clients and your features.

See the "Protocol support" topic, especially the SFTP and FTPS columns.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP protocol sends the data across the network or internet in "Clear Text". This means that anyone watching the FTP traffic (the tools to do this are freely available) can see that actual data being sent. This includes the FTP login name and password.  Once they see this, they can login to that server with the captured login information and access all of the rest of the files on that server.

Many FTP tools also include the ability to use other protocols that encrypt the logins, passwords and the data being sent or received with the server.  These are SFTP and FTPS. See some additional information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol about these secure protocols as well as how hackers use FTP gain access to sensitive data at http://blog.goanywheremft.com/2012/12/04/hacking-file-transfers/.

I hope this helps...